# How can i display animated svg file in iOS without using UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, svg-animate

Currently i am using `UIWebView` to display animated svg file in my native iOS application.

This works fine except the CPU usage is constantly being on higher side as long as app is in foreground.

Is there any better way to display svg file without using `UIwebView`

I have already tried many third party libraries but all works only with static svg file not animated svgs

I have tried following

https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG

https://github.com/exyte/Macaw

https://github.com/onmyway133/Snowflake

https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

My app supports **iOS 9** and above , My code is in **Swift3**

Here is the link of on of the svg file that i am trying to display

http://www.mediafire.com/file/04ojy6t4e3c41lv/03d.svg

Comment: There just another SVG lib with Core Animation support, https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit, but I never tried it.

Comment: Nope... It's not working

Comment: Do you know any library to display animated SVG files that is using `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

First install the pod in your podfile

```
pod `SVGKit`
```

Then import the library in your view controller file

```
import SVGKit
```

Then create SVGKImageObjectView object and add it to your view

```
let svgImage = SVGKFastImageView(svgkImage : SVGKImage(contentOf:Bundle.main.url(forResource: "animated", withExtension : "svg")!))
self.view.addSubview(svgImage)
```

To animate the SVG You can use play function

```
svgImage.svgKImage.play()
```

You can also set your frame and layout

```
svgImage.frame  = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height: 200)
svgImage.center = self.view.center
```

Answer (score -1):

You should take look at [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) !

This library is based on core animation.

Refer [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kamil.powalowski/paths-animation-of-svg-file-using-svgkit-3d25e7774c89),

First install pod or manually install SVGKit into your project.

Then drag and drop your svg file in to your project.

Then you can do something like,

```
  UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 300, 300)];

myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

[self.view addSubview:myView];

 // SVGKImage *image = [SVGKImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"animated-svg-icon"];

SVGKImage *image = [SVGKImage imageNamed:@"cd-icon.svg"];

[self animateCALayer:image.CALayerTree duration:2.0];
[myView.layer addSublayer:image.CALayerTree];
```

here `cd-icon.svg` is the svg image. Put all the html,js and css files with it in your bundle! (put whole folder of svg in your project)

If you get any error related `CocoaLumberjack` then install `pod 'CocoaLumberjack'` in your project and replace `@import CocoaLumberjack;` with `#import "CocoaLumberjack.h"` in `SVGKit-prefix.pch`

Follow everything step by step as I mentioned. And you are done. You will displaying svg in `UIView` instead of `webview`.

Comment: I have already tried  SVGKit ... but it doesn't work with animated svg .... Thanks

Comment: are you using animated svg ?

Comment: [https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-svg-icon/](https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-svg-icon/) this svg animated in my case

Comment: It's sample code doesn't even work properly ... at least in Xcode 8.3

Comment: if you running sample code of library then check scheme! you shouldn't run framework!

Comment: I know ... the example runs ... but almost no animation happens

Comment: download my demo (SVGDemo.zip) from [https://github.com/ketan-parmar/SVGDemoForiOS/blob/master/SVGDemo.zip](https://github.com/ketan-parmar/SVGDemoForiOS/blob/master/SVGDemo.zip)

Comment: SVGDemo folder is empty

Comment: download from here [https://github.com/ketan-parmar/SVGDemoForiOS/blob/master/SVGDemoForiOS.zip](https://github.com/ketan-parmar/SVGDemoForiOS/blob/master/SVGDemoForiOS.zip)

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/04ojy6t4e3c41lv/03d.svg Try this file in your demo ... nothing being displayed

Comment: if specific svg is not working then it should be issue of svg i think!

Comment: and there is only one file with extension svg in the link you have provided. you required all supporting file with it like htmp, css etc to run on iOS. download file from [https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-svg-icon/](https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-svg-icon/) here and see you will have one folder of multiple files!

Comment: I have around 30 svg file. none of the svg works .... even though all of the svg workd just fine if i display it inside UIwebView

Comment: If i display it in UIwebView i did not require anything other than svg file itself

Comment: yeah for webview you not require other files!